# jquery change event not calling for input element

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am using [jRange sliders](http://nitinhayaran.github.io/jRange/demo/) and it requires an input filed, so i created that field, and jRange slider created fine..

My Code

```
<input type="hidden"  class="js-slider" value=0 />

<script>
    jQuery('.js-slider').jRange({
       from: 0,
       to: 50,
       step: 1,
       scale: [0,25,50],
       format: '%s',
       width: 200,
       showLabels: true,
       theme:"theme-blue"
    });

    jQuery(".js-slider").change(function(){
        console.log("changed");
    });
</script>
```

Now the problem is when slider changed the input field value is changed but the change event is not calling ..What is the problem, How to solve this..?

Comment: Have you tried with `.input(fn)` method?

Comment: no i will check that.

Comment: use the api callbacks from plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes in value to hidden elements don't automatically fire the [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change) event. So, in that case you can use `onstatechange` of `jRange Slider` like,

```
onstatechange: function(){
    $(".js-slider").trigger('change'); // call trigger or change() from here
}
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/qaetx8s1/)

```
jQuery(".js-slider").change(function(){
    console.log(this.value); // get the value
});
```

Comment: I understood onstatechange called when slider changes, but how can get the value of the changed slider

Answer (score 1):

You will need to attach `change` event in `onstatechange()` callback method, see below sample code

```
<script>
    jQuery('.js-slider').jRange({
       from: 0,
       to: 50,
       step: 1,
       scale: [0,25,50],
       format: '%s',
       width: 200,
       showLabels: true,
       theme:"theme-blue",
       onstatechange: function(){
            $(".js-slider").change() //trigger change even on element
       }
    });

    jQuery(".js-slider").change(function(){
        console.log("changed");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
jQuery('.range-slider').jRange({

    from: 0,

    to: 100,

    step: 1,

    scale: [0,25,50,75,100],

    format: '%s',

    width: 230,

    showScale: false,

    showLabels: true,

    isRange: false,

    onstatechange: function(){

        jQuery('.range-slider').trigger('change');

    }

});

jQuery('.range-slider').on('change', function() {

    console.log(this.value);

});
```